# I could join Software Recommendations during private beta without committing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, private-beta

I took a look at the [Software Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) proposal on Area 51. There was a big link saying "visit the site now!" and out of curiosity I clicked it.
To my surprise, I got the regular sign-up screen from Stack Exchange. So, I entered my credentials, expecting to see a warning that only committed users could do this. Instead, I could just join the site, despite never having committed to it, and despite the fact that the site is still in private beta.

I'm guessing this is a bug?

Comment: @ProgramFOX, Bart: you are right, it's a duplicate.